# Defining function in Python accepts (x, *args), but not (*args, x). Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have recently begun teaching myself Python and I have an inquiry regarding defining functions. I read about the `*args` and `**args` possibilites in functions and decided to try them out. I tried to make a very simple calculator by trying to make this function in IDLE:

```
def test(*args, tool):
    total = 0
    if(tool == '+' or tool == 'plus'):
        for a in args:
            total += a
        return total
```

However, when I got passed the first line, Python threw this error at me:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

At first, I didn't know what I did wrong, so I tried to `type()` them both and realized that *args is a tuple and **args is a dictionary. So I understood how Python would be confused when trying to convert a string of letters into a tuple and then finding what might be the `tool` part of the code.

However, when I switched place on the *args and tool: `def test(tool, *args)`, I wasn't met with any errors at all and the code ran as expected (strangely, without the tool parameter at all). However, when I tried to call the function this way: `test(4, 2, 3, 'tool')`, it once again threw an error at me, complaining about how it can't add together ints and strings.

What is going on?

Comment: because you don't know how many elements *args has

Comment: `*args` in a function definition means "put the rest of the arguments into a list". It does not support "put the rest of the arguments into a list except for the next argument declared which is separate".

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But why does def `(tool, *args)` work then? Is it because it first looks for the tool argument and THEN for the *args argument? Does it bypass the tool argument and go straight for the *args argument?
Also, why does my function work as though tool is equal to + or plus, even though I didn't input it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*args` must be at the end of a function call. This is because if there are arguments after `*args`, Python has no way of knowing when `*args` ends and the rest of the arguments begin. If there are a set number of arguments at the start, then `*args`, it knows to stop at the end of the function.

Python is an interpreted language, so it will read the function from left to right and assign variables as it goes. Take the following:

```
def foo(bar, *args):
    print("Hello, world!", bar, args)
```

If I pass in `foo(3, 4, 5, 6)` Python says, "Okay, we'll set `bar` to 3. Then, the rest of our arguments go into `args`. That's `(4, 5, 6)`".

Now with the arguments the other way round:

```
def foo(*args, bar):
    print("Hello, world!", bar, args)
```

With the same arguments, Python will say, "The rest of the arguments can be put into `args`. That's `(3, 4, 5, 6)`. Wait, what about `bar`? We have nothing left!" And so it throws an error.

With your function, `test`, you can't input three numbers and a string if you're adding up `*args`. You have to pass `tool` in first, then the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is just because of the interpreter (or compiler in other languages' cases). When you define a function the interpreter looks for arguments, then extra arguments, and then keyword arguments; for properly explaining:

In this case, the interpreter will find just one argument:

```
def (myArg):
```

In this case, the interpreter will find an argument and 'remaining' arguments, so it knows how to map the first argument and then the others.

```
def (myArg, *args):
```

But in this case, the interpreter looks for a `list` of arguments so it will take all of them and pack them into args; what happens to myArg then?

```
def(*args, myArg):
```

There are no more arguments because it already packed all of them into args, just because the interpreter doesn't know when args ends.